# Which apps are affected by the SYNC icon in Power Control Bar?

Tags: sync

I can turn sync on/off in the Power Control bar. Which applications actually use this sync setting? Is that only Google-based products (calendar, contacts, gmail) or does it also influence apps like IMAP email, Evernote, etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you mean the **Auto-sync**. Go to "Settings -> Accounts & sync". You will find which apps are using the sync function under **Manage accounts**. Only the apps in the list will be influenced.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, auto-sync seems to be the right name. The list confirms that it is only my google account that is influenced by this setting (unfortunately, as it would make sense for other apps to use the auto-sync on/off setting as well)

Answer (score 0):

To identify the app that is causing sync. Go to "Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications-> click "Uninstall update" for the app (This is due to the updates that added background sync. only few app show this). These apps are the culprits to drain your battery.